# replace IP address in file

Tags: regex, powershell, ip

I want to replace IP addresses in a file.
Example file

```
255.255.255.22<
255.255.255.222<
255.255.255.22;
255.255.255.222;
```

The files are config files. Say, I need to replace 255.255.255.22 but not 255.255.255.222. The IP to be replaced may have either `;` or `<` after the IP. Using `.\d{1,3}\D` in a search and replace I end up losing the character after the IP.

Comment: Try `'.\d{1,3}(?=\D)'` - the `(?=)` syntax [is a lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) - it matches against the following text, but does not capture it or include it in the match content, so it stays in the original place.

Comment: Thanks that works (?=\D) is what was needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
"(\d{1,3}\\.){3}(\d{2})(?=[<;])"
```

if you want to match IP's with 1-3 digits at the end.

try this:

`"(\d{1,3}\\.){3}(\d{1,3})(?=[<;])"`